# Templates in C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, templates

can we declare a `template` function in a normal class with out a template class or is it should be always inside a `template class` ?

Comment: I think you meant "class template". A class template like `template <typename T> struct Foo { };` is a kind of template, but not a kind of class. Similarly, a "function template" is another kind of template, and not a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> can we declare a template function in a normal class with out a template class

Yes we can. For example

```
class demo
{
   public:
   template <typename T>
   void func(const T& x) { 
      //do stuffs 
   }
};

int main()
{
   demo d;
   d.func<int>(5);
}
```

is perfectly valid

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can have template functions in non-templated classes too, e.g.:

```
struct X {
    template<class T>
    void f(const T& t) {
        // ...
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can , but make sure your definition and declaration of the template function is in the header files. If you want to know more why is this like that or more about templates in general i can recommend you this book [Templates - Complete Guide](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201734842)